# Having trouble with insertChildBefore and insertChildAfter in AS3

Tags: xml, actionscript-3

I have an XML document:

```
var xml:XML = new XML(<rootNode>            
                <head> 
                    <meta name="template" content="Default" />
                </head>
                <mainSection>
                    <itemList>
                        <item>
                            <video src={this.videoURL}  />
                            <img  src={this.src}></img>
                        </item>
                    </itemList>
                </mainSection>
            </rootNode>);
```

What I'd like to do, is when certain conditions are me, insert another  at the beginning of itemList.

```
var newNode:XMLList = new XMLList("<item><video src=\"" + _videoSource + "\"></video></item>");
```

I'm able to generate and trace newNode just fine, but whenever I try to add it using `insertChildBefore`, it always returns undefined.

```
var contentNode:XML = new XML(xml.mainSection.itemList.item);
xml.insertChildBefore(contentNode ,newNode)
```

`contentNode` always traces fine, but it always fails when trying `insertChildBefore` or `insertChildAfter`. The weird thing is, if I make `contentNode` less specific (like `xml.mainSection`) then it works as expected.

Thanks for any help, this is driving me insane!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two problems here (I've now tested this code - it should work for you):

1. The variable `xml` is not the direct parent of the `item` node you are inserting.  You're calling `insertChildBefore` on the `xml` node, but your `contentNode` is not its direct child.
2. The `contentNode` variable you're trying to insert ahead of is a *copy* of the node you want; you shouldn't be creating a brand new XML object.

Try this instead:

```
var contentNode:XML = xml.mainSection.itemList.item[0];
var parentNode:XML = xml.mainSection.itemList[0];
parentNode.insertChildBefore( contentNode, newNode[0] );
```

Comment: thanks! I think we're on the right track here but parentNode is coming up as null.

Comment: Alright, I've updated the answer with something that works for me.