# Add item to xml file in flex builder

Tags: xml, actionscript-3, apache-flex, flexbuilder, addchild

I'm a little new to flex builder. I have a xml file successfully imported in my program.
But I want it to be possible to add items to it. I figured it had to be with `insertChildAfter`. This is what I got, but it won't work and can't find the solution.

example XML-structure:

```
<deelnemers>    
  <deelnemer>   
   <totem>timka</totem>
   <aantalActiviteiten>2</aantalActiviteiten>
   <actID>0</actID>
   <actID>1</actID>
  </deelnemer>  
  <deelnemer>   
   <totem>hop</totem>
   <aantalActiviteiten>3</aantalActiviteiten>
   <actID>0</actID>
   <actID>1</actID>
   <actID>3</actID>
  </deelnemer>  
</deelnemers>
```

function:

```
    protected function button1_clickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void{
      totem = myTotem.text; //Get information out of inputField
      deelnemers.insertChildAfter(<totem>{totem}</totem>,
                                  <actID>{ID}</actID>);
    listDeelnemers.refresh();}
```

Comment: You should explain more about what isn't working exactly.

Comment: Well, the function isn't adding the item. so the purpose of the function is to add <actID>{number}</actID> after <totem>{totem}</totem> but it does nothing

Comment: See this QA: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5942414/trouble-with-insertchildafter-for-xml-in-actionsctipt-3